# Android, how to combined graph using GraphView Library

Tags: android, android-graphview

I would like to create combined horizontal and scrollable graph like on the image below using GraphView library:

[image]

How can i do it please?

Many Thanks for any sample.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot mix LineGraph with BarGraph in GraphView

But multiple series in a GraphView with different color and scrollability looks like this:
(You will have to do some tricks regarding the viewport because if a column is shown, it extends the viewport to fit in the graph - it has a width of 1 unit.)

[image: GraphView multiple series bar chart]

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GraphView graphView = new BarGraphView(this, "Graph Title");

    GraphViewData[] data1 = new GraphViewData[] {
            new GraphViewData(1, 5.0d),
            new GraphViewData(2, 3.0d),
            new GraphViewData(3, 4.0d),
            new GraphViewData(4, 3.0d),
            new GraphViewData(5, 7.0d),
            new GraphViewData(6, 6.0d),
            new GraphViewData(7, 7.0d),
            new GraphViewData(8, 2.0d),
    };
    GraphViewSeriesStyle style1 = new GraphViewSeriesStyle();
    style1.setValueDependentColor(new ValueDependentColor() {
        @Override
        public int get(GraphViewDataInterface data) {
            if(((int)data.getX())%2 == 0) {
                return Color.rgb(200, 60, 0);
            }
            else {
                return Color.rgb(60, 200, 0);
            }
        }
    });
    GraphViewSeries series1 = new GraphViewSeries("Series 1", style1, data1);

    graphView.setManualYAxisBounds(10,0);
    graphView.setViewPort(1,3.99999);
    graphView.setScrollable(true);
    graphView.addSeries(series1);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.graph1);
    layout.addView(graphView);
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/graph1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for Your snippet. Do You know how to add margins  between bars?

Comment: You might try placing the bars at shifted x coordinates.
`new GraphViewData(1, 5.0d),`
`new GraphViewData(2, 3.0d),`
`new GraphViewData(3.5, 4.0d),`
`new GraphViewData(4.5, 3.0d),`
`new GraphViewData(6, 7.0d),`
...
Or try editing the library source itself and change bar width there.